# Random Digit Data Masking on Id_number in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica, data-masking

I need to mask 4 digit of id_number rondomly between 6th and 12th digits.

Example:
555444888777 --> 55544x8x8xx7

I wrote following code but it is rondom for every 2 digit. Is there any solution for rondomly masking with given *intervals* and *how many digits for needed to mask* in Vertica ?

`SELECT OVERLAYB(OVERLAYB(OVERLAYB(OVERLAYB('555444888777', 'x', 5+RANDOMINT(2)),'x', 7+RANDOMINT(2)),'x', 9+RANDOMINT(2)),'x',11+RANDOMINT(2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to randomly replace a digit with an 'x' at , randomly, the first or second digit after positions 5,7,9 and 11, as you coded it, then create a function as I did, so you don't need to re-code the nested OVERLAYB() calls every time.

You can replace 5,7,9 and 11 with a RANDOMINT() call, too, if you want more variance.

If, however, you want to vary the number of replacements (from 4 times to another number of times), you will have to re-write the function for a different number of replacements. Or go through the trouble of writing a UDx (User Defined Extension), in C++, Java, R or Python.

Check the Vertica docu for that; start here:
https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/CREATEFUNCTIONUDF.htm?zoom_highlight=create%20function

Having said that, here goes the function with your same functionality, and its test:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maskrand( 
  s VARCHAR(256)
) 
RETURN VARCHAR(256) 
AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    OVERLAYB(
      OVERLAYB(
        OVERLAYB(
          OVERLAYB(
            s
          , 'x'
          , 5+RANDOMINT(2)
          )
          ,'x'
        , 7+RANDOMINT(2)
        )
        ,'x'
      , 9+RANDOMINT(2)
      )
      ,'x'
    , 11+RANDOMINT(2)
    )
  );
END;

-- test ...
WITH indata(s) AS (
          SELECT '555444888777'
UNION ALL SELECT '666333444888'
) 
SELECT
  s, maskrand(s) AS masked
FROM indata;
-- out       s       |    masked    
-- out --------------+--------------
-- out  555444888777 | 5554x48x8xx7
-- out  666333444888 | 6663x3x4x88x
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit crazy, but seems to work:

```sql
with my_range as (
             select  6 as n
   union all select  7 as n
   union all select  8 as n
   union all select  9 as n
   union all select 10 as n
   union all select 11 as n
   union all select 12 as n),
random_positions as (
   select n
     from my_range
    order by random()
    limit 4),
quartiles as (
   select n,
          ntile(4) over(order by n) as quartile
     from random_positions),
sorted_positions as (
   select max(case when quartile = 1 then n end) as random1,
          max(case when quartile = 2 then n end) as random2,
          max(case when quartile = 3 then n end) as random3,
          max(case when quartile = 4 then n end) as random4
     from quartiles)
select '555444888777' as string_original,
       overlay(
         overlay(
            overlay(
               overlay('555444888777' placing 'x' from random1)
               placing 'x' from random2)
            placing 'x' from random3)
         placing 'x' from random4)
       as string_masked
  from sorted_positions;
```

Sample executions:

```
$ vsql -f tmp.sql
 string_original | string_masked
-----------------+---------------
 555444888777    | 55544xx8xx77
(1 row)


$ vsql -f tmp.sql
 string_original | string_masked
-----------------+---------------
 555444888777    | 55544xx8x7x7
(1 row)


$ vsql -f tmp.sql
 string_original | string_masked
-----------------+---------------
 555444888777    | 55544x8x8x7x
(1 row)
```

Explanation:

- `my_range` builds a recordset with numbers from 6 to 12
- `random_positions` sorts the recordset randomly, only returning 4 positions
- `quartiles` assigns the quartile to each random position so `sorted_positions` can pivot the results into a single record
- finally, the last `select` applies the [OVERLAY function](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/OVERLAY.htm) four times at the four random positions